# Triggering -moz-box not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

I want a certain box (centered both vertically and horizontally) to appear after a certain trigger, illustrated in this fiddleJS: https://jsfiddle.net/7yvmwkqf/

For example:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  outer.style.display = '-webkit-box';
  outer.style.display = '-moz-box';
  outer.style.display = 'box';
}, 2000);
```

This works fine on Safari and Chrome, but on Firefox, the box isn't centered.

Anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: it doesn't work because you are rewriting `outer.style.display` instead of appending it, if you changed the second statement into `outer.style.display += '-moz-box'` it will work

Comment: hmmm on second thought it is strange that it works just by changing the second statement, the third statement should need the change too because it is overwriting `outer.style.display` !!?

Comment: @niceman why does it work using `+=`?

Comment: Because you're using an outdated syntax?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I think the outdated syntax needed vendor's prefix (`-moz`), the new syntax doesn't require it

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.